# What does "entry" means in CPU cache?

Tags: intel, cpu-cache

When I read the Intel's system programming guide, I found this:
[image]

The Store buffer will improve the write performance, so what is its size? What does entry means here?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. You've posted a graphic that tells you what its size is, so why are you asking us what its size is? I get that you don't understand what an entry is, but it also seems you don't understand what a store is.

Comment: I think OP meant the size of an entry. Just for my curiosity, how it is decided? Surely you can do stores at different granularity.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think the store means move data from register to memory, am I right? So move one byte and move 32 bytes (through avx) are both store OP, the entry here is one byte or 32 bytes?

Comment: @IsuruH See my answer. Whatever the granularity of the store is, it's still a store.

Comment: What I meant is, if the store is a byte and buffer entry is 8 bytes, wouldn't it be wasting space.

Comment: The only time an optimization guide would declare a value regarding *all* i3-i5-i7 processors was probably when only the first gen (Nehalem) was out - you should probably look for a newer doc online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store buffer, as its name implies, buffers stores. So each entry in the store buffer is a store operation performed by the CPU.

Comment: And what the size of store operation? 1byte to ?    Store buffer need space hold the data, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm sure you can do better this that answer. Do it!

Comment: @templexxx The size of a store operation depends on the CPU. You can check the CPU's documentation to see what stores it supports. For typical x86 CPUs, it's either 32 bits or 64 bits. By "store", we literally mean an attempt by the CPU to store something in memory.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thank you for your patience! If my CPU has AVX instructions, when I use a instruction like VMOVDQA to store 32bytes to memory, is it a store operation too? So the entry will be 256 bits?

Comment: @templexxx It depends on the specifics of the microarchitecture. Haswell and Sandy Bridge do it differently. You could have wider entries, you can use multiple entries, you can bypass the store buffers.